# Why is arc4random returning outlandish values?

Tags: objective-c

I am calling arc4random in a function in my iOS application to generate random values from -5 to 6.

```
double num;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    num = (arc4random() % 11) - 5;
    NSLog(@"%0.0f", num);
}
```

I get the following output from console.

```
2012-05-01 20:25:41.120 Project32[8331:fb03] 0
2012-05-01 20:25:41.121 Project32[8331:fb03] 1
2012-05-01 20:25:41.122 Project32[8331:fb03] 4294967295
```

0 and 1 are values within range, but wowww, where did 4294967295 come from?

Changing `arc4random()` to `rand()` fixes the problem, but `rand()`, of course, requires seeding.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `num`? Probably but just probably an `unsigned int`? :)

Comment: I'm guessing that num is an unsigned integer?

Comment: Sorry, I just included the declaration of num.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`arc4random()` returns a `u_int32_t` -- that's an unsigned integer, one that doesn't represent negative values. Every time `arc4random() % 11` comes up with a number 0 ≤ n < 5, you subtract 5 and wrap around to a very large number.

`double`s *can* represent negative numbers, of course, but you're not converting to `double` until it's too late. Stick a cast in there:

```
 num = (double)(arc4random() % 11) - 5;
```

to promote the result of the modulo before the subtraction, and everything will be okay.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. `arc4random()` returns an unsigned integer, which can overflow with subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
arc4random_uniform(11) - 5;
```

instead.

From the man page:

```
arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number
 less than upper_bound.  arc4random_uniform() is recommended over con-
 structions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias"
 when the upper bound is not a power of two.
```

Comment: Thank you, what is "modulo bias"?

Comment: @JustinCase: Say a random number generator produced only numbers 1 to 5. If you had `rand() % 2` you are more likely to get 1 than 0. That is *modulo bias*. Obviously the bias for `arc4_random() % upper_bound` (where `upper_bound` is not a power of 2) is not as huge as my example, but it still exists.

Comment: This page also has an example - http://romhack.wikia.com/wiki/Random_number_generator

Comment: This is good advice in general, but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau you are right, I only tested printing the results, NSLog(@"%d", arc4random(11)-5);

Comment: @danielbeard While your answer provides good tips and insight, I agree with Jacques in that this won't solve Justin's problem. Downvoted for that, but otherwise, useful answer and information. :)