# Why is arc4random() behaving different when storing it in a variable or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    int chance = -5;
    int rand = arc4random() % 100;   // Number from 0 to 99
    if (rand <= chance) {            // This will never happen
        NSLog(@"This is... NOT POSSIBLE");
    }
```

Effectively, this never happens. But

```
    int chance = -5;
    if (arc4random() % 100 <= chance) {
        NSLog(@"This is... NOT POSSIBLE");
    }
```

Here, instead of storing it in a variable, I placed the random number expression directly in the condition. And **the condition is fulfilled** (sometimes).

Why is that? How can I debug this behavior?

Comment: same root problem as [Why is arc4random() returning outlandish values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406216)

Comment: However, this is ***not related to Xcode at all.*** @Omega, any specific reason you added the `xcode` tag?

Comment: @H2CO3: I was unsure if it was related to the compiler XD. Thanks.

Comment: @Omega Well, it isn't particularly, but it's better to keep in mind that **Xcode is not a compiler.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type promotion rules.

`arc4random` returns an *unsigned* value.  That means in your second case, the `-5` gets promoted to that same unsigned type, turning it into `4294967291`.  4+ billion is definitely larger than any number 0-99!

Let's walk through what happens in both of your examples.

1. From your first example, in this line:

   ```
   int rand = arc4random() % 100;
   ```

   `arc4random()` returns an unsigned value.  So then it looks like:

   ```
   int rand = someUnsignedNumber % 100;
   ```

   The `100` is a signed int, so it gets promoted to the same type as `someUnsignedNumber`, and the `%` operation is applied.  After that you have:

   ```
   int rand = someUnsignedNumberBetween0And99;
   ```

   Assigning that unsigned number to `int rand` makes it back into a signed number.  Your comparison then goes forward as expected.
2. In the second example, you have this line:

   ```
   if (arc4random() % 100 <= chance)
   ```

   The same things happen with `arc4random() % 100`, yielding something like:

   ```
   if (someUnsignedNumberBetween0And99 <= chance)
   ```

   But here, `chance` is a signed number.  It gets promoted, changing its value as described above, and you end up with the strange behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 5):

Silly, silly type system of C... If you read the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) for `arc4random()`, you find out that its prototype is

```
u_int32_t arc4random(void);
```

So it returns an **unsigned** integer.

When comparing its - unsigned - result with another integer, the unsignedness "wins": the other value (`-5`) is promoted to the unsigned type (`u_int32_t` in this case), it rolls over (since unsigned integer "underflow" is designed to work like this in C - you'll get `2 ^ 32 - 5`) and so an "erroneous" (i. e. behaving-as-unexpected) comparison occurs.

When you explicitly assign the value to an `int` (i. e. **signed**) variable, this promotion does not occur since the comparison is between two signed types, so it is evaluated as you would expect.